# Google Places API: retrieve restaurant in Rome

Tags: json, get, google-places-api, postman

It's hard for me to understand why Postman is returning me restaurant in US even if I'm restricting the research to `postal_code:00100|country:IT` (00100 = Rome zip code, IT = Italy)

This is my GET:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurant&components=postal_code:00100|country:IT&key=MYSECRETKEY
```

[image]

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know why is it happening but you can check out the example Text search request here https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

An alternate, all you will need is Location and Radius of the place. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components filtering is not supported in Places API text search.

Take a look at official documentation, there is no `components` parameter available:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests

To bias your results you should use the `location` and `radius` parameters.

The components filtering is supported only in Geocoding API. So you can solve the issue in two steps.

- Get position of the postal code using Geocoding API
- Search restaurants using Places API text search and location from the first step

E.g.

Get location of postal code 00100

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A00100%7Ccountry%3AIT&key=YOUR_API_KEY[image]

Now use coordinate 41.9228369,12.5014301 to search restaurants in 5km radius

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurant&location=41.9228369%2C12.5014301&radius=5000&key=YOUR_API_KEY[image]

Hope this helps!